# Has anyone been able to use 21CFR Part 11 with Embedded Signing?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

There is a guide on the Docusign website (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded-cfrpart11/) for this, but I keep getting the error `"This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient."` which suggests that embedded signing is not possible.

Has anyone been able to use the guide above?

Answer (score 0):

CFR Part 11 is possible with embedded signing but as the how to guide shows you will need to use the SMS for access & signatures authentication method.

`Running this example requires that you have a CFR Part 11 account with the "SMS for access & signatures" authentication method enabled.`

You can contact [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US&_gl=1*1trey7l*_ga*MjMzNTI3NjIyLjE2NjUxNjQ1NDA.*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTY3MTA0ODAzMS4xMC4xLjE2NzEwNDgxMTEuNjAuMC4w&_ga=2.78041684.1730728370.1670866286-233527622.1665164540) to get that enabled.

Comment: Will try this asap and let you know if it worked! Thank you!